# How to select data packages for annotations in user surrounding

Tags: swift, firebase, annotations, mapkit

I have some questions. I am trying to program a map where you can see annotations which were uploaded by different users before. I am using firebase as database and mapkit. I have no clue how to select the data-packages of my databank in the surrounding of the user to download. Has someone inspirations for me?

Comment: are you asking how to structure and filter data based on GeoLocation in Firebase?

Comment: If so, see https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc